# Where is 'Operations' in Central Administration 2013

Tags: central-administration

I have been able to find a lot of resources for what I need IF what I was using was SharePoint Central Administration 2010 because there is a lot of reference to 'Operations' link which doesnt exist in my Central Administration 2013 making my life very difficult.

Comment: What are you trying to access with in the CA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no more Operations tab in SharePoint 2010 or above versions in Central admin.

Operations tab available untill MOSS 2007. Now they spread-ed it into multiple tab and make it simple.

I think it is better if you tell us what options u looking in operations or what action you want to perform.

Comment: thanks. It actually makes it very painful to find things when the only referencse to where said item is on the internet are using older versions of Central Adminstration. It would be great if MS would stop moving things around

Answer (score 0):

how to reach there in sharepoint 2013 : To check the deployment status, browse to Central Administration > Operations tab > Solution management under Global Configuration. The solution(s) will be marked as Globally Deployed.